# Call vuex store without mapState

Tags: vue.js, vuex

So I'm experimenting with a new project created with vue cli, where I am using router and VueX

So in my HelloWorld.vue file, I've got this code in the script section:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
   computed: mapState({
    msg: 'nombre'
  }),
```

Is there a more direct way of calling values in the state?, like for example I would like to do

```
msg: store.nombre
```

My vuex store is defined in the root main.js like this:

```
//vuex
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    nombre: "POS vuex"
  }  
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually I was looking for this way:

```
msg: this.$store.state.nombre
```

(I was missing the ".state." part)

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you're using `mapState` as computed you can actually call these states with `this` in that component - in the template or script section:

Use the `...` operator on your `mapState` and you're done:

Example:

Your store:

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    nombre: "POS vuex",
    otherState: "abc",
    anotherState: "efg"
  }  
});
```

Your component:

```
<template>
  <div id="test">
    {{ nombre }}
    {{ otherState }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'hello',
   methods: {
     logState() {
       console.log(this.anotherState);
     }
   },
   computed: {
     ...mapState(["nombre", "otherState", "anotherState"]),
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the the [mapState helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)

```
computed: {
  ...mapState('moduleOne', ['keyOne', 'keyTwo'])
}
```

which lets you access the values via `this.keyOne` and `this.keyTwo` inside your component.

You can also add your store to the [root vue instance](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components) and access your state inside your components via the global `this.$store` directive.

```
this.$store.module.keyOne
this.$store.module.keyTwo
```

Additionally if you need to access your store from outside your components you can also export the store and import it directly from non-component code.

If you export your store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import moduleTwo from './modules/moduleOne'
import moduleOne from './modules/moduleTwo'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true,
  modules: {
    moduleOne,
    moduleTwo
  }
})

export default store
```

You can import it anywhere you need to access state, getters, actions, and mutations.

```
import store from '@/store'

console.log(store.state.moduleOne.keyone)
store.dispatch('moduleOne/actionOne', { keyOne: valOne })
store.getters['moduleOne/getterOne']
store.commit('moduleOne/mutationOne', data)
```

Answer (score -1):

Call you'r state in **created** method of vuex.

THanks